# color is not applying on element p

Tags: html, css, colors

///html

```
     <p className="movieDesc__download">Download Links</p>
     <button className="movieDesc__downloadButton">Download</button>
     <p className="movieDesc__trailer">Trailer</p>
```

///css

```
.movieDesc>p{
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: rgb(247, 239, 239);
} 
.movieDesc__trailer{
   color: #DD2E44;
  }
```

///image of p the default color is white
.

[[image: This is the image of element p you can see no color is applied]]

Comment: are you using react. if not then use `class=""` instead of `className=""`

Comment: check the answer down

Answer (score -1):

```css
p{
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: rgb(247, 239, 239);
} 
.movieDesc__trailer{
   color: #DD2E44;
  }
```

```html
    <p class="movieDesc__download">Download Links</p>
    <button class="movieDesc__downloadButton">Download</button>
    <p class="movieDesc__trailer">Trailer</p>
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention i am using react

Comment: it works fine. check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/maub84po/).